# css input submit link

Tags: css

I have this html:

```
      <form id="REVIEW" method="post" action="/SortReviews">
        <fieldset class="sort">
          <input type="submit" value="$ratingLine"/>            
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

I want to give the submit button some css, so it looks like a link.

```
{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Just noting that setting a button to look like a link breaks a few usability rules. Buttons that perform an action and postback should look like buttons.

Comment: @Steve Costello - What does "postback" have to do with usability? No end user looks at a button and thinks "oh, that's a postback!" I think doing this is a great way to respect [the opposite of fitt's law](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html) while also respecting HTTP GET as a safe method.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
form input[type="submit"]{

    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Is this not what you're looking for?

The other option, as already noted, is to use javascript to submit the form onclick of a anchor element:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.review.submit()">submit</a>
```

with your form having an attribute: `name="review"`

Comment: I am sure you would need to set also: `margin:0; padding:0;`

Answer (score 2):

You should assign a class to the button

```
<input type="submit" value="$ratingLine" class="link-lookalike"/>
```

and in your css file (*or inside a `<style type="text/css"></style>` tag*) use

```
.link-lookalike {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

this way you can assign the class to different buttons in your page (*if required*), and they will all get the same look.

Answer (score 1):

Use the button element:

```
<button type="submit">$ratingLine</button>
```

Comment: Why was this down-voted? Input elements have restrictions on how much you can style them, button elements don't.

Comment: While this answer is useful it doesn't exactly answer the question. Probably that's where the down vote came from, though a few years passed since then...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class, for example `"submitClass"`.

```
<input type="submit" value="$ratingLine" class="submitClass"/>

   .submitClass {
        background: none;    
        border: none;    
        color: blue;    
        text-decoration: underline;    
        cursor: pointer;
   }
```

Comment: You don't need to put a class on something to style it. "#review input" would work fine in that example.

Comment: @Tim, but that would style every other input element he decides to put in the form.. In the example code it would work, but why not make it more extensible ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it with html and css:

```
<p><form class='input-to-link-form'><input type="submit" value="Place your order" class="input-to-link"></form> and make payment.</p>

.input-to-link {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #0088cc;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.input-to-link-form {
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
```