# How to create a text only button?

Tags: html, css, button

How can I create a button that only shows the text. Similar to an *hyperlink* but it has to keep the `<button>` properties.

Comment: If I'm reading your post correctly, you want a hyperlink...

Comment: See [css input submit link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734584/css-input-submit-link)

Comment: If you want good answers, I recommend using some basic grammar and punctuation, as well as providing more information about what, exactly, you're looking to do.

Comment: @ Richard JP Le Guen i have tried to write with class but it doesnot work

Comment: @Brian Driscoll how can i using hyperlink know on the server  if it is clicked ?

Comment: @Vahan set the `href` attribute of the hyperlink so that it will submit your form (or call the appropriate controller, since you're using JSP)

Comment: @Brian Driscol i set the href atribut and then i check in teh servlet if req.getparametr with its name != null, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Vahan please post some of your code

Comment: @Brian Driscol html: <th> <a href="" name="NAME1"> NAME </a></th> code inside servlet doGet method: if(req.getParameter("NAME1")!=null)                                { RequestDispatcher disp = req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Error.jsp"); disp.forward(req, resp); return ; }

Comment: @Vahan can you please edit your question and add the full code for your JSP? I have a feeling that there's a very simple solution but it's tough to explain w/ so little code.

Comment: @Brian Driscol my full code is very large and didn't wirte this part in the code, i seems get the solution, i take the text as img, and in the server i check if img.x and img.y !=null

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Assuming you're starting with a `button` element:

```
<button class="astext">hello, world</button>
```

All you have to do is take away all of the default CSS styling:

```
.astext {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Of course, there's no way to tell that the resulting text is actually a button. I suppose you could throw in a `cursor:pointer` or some `:hover` rules.

Maybe you're making an easter egg, maybe you don't *want* people to know it can be clicked.

Comment: in this case all buttons in the page will be as text, but i need onlu some of them

Comment: @Vahan No, if you use a class (such as `astext`), then it will only apply to the buttons that have that class.

Comment: @Vahan NO, only buttons with the class attribute set to "astext" will be set as text-only.

Comment: @Vahan Do you have a link? I messed around with JSFiddle to get this to work, but I only did it in Chrome. Other browsers might be a little pickier.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc which link? I work with mozila. I want to be a button as text because i have a table first row is table atributes list: name etc, i want to sort table columns when i click on column name,i osrt with jsp

Comment: @Vahan When you click on the column name, does it go to a different page with the table sorted? Or is the sorting done by JavaScript, on the same page?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc it will reload this page with jsp

Comment: @Vahan Then you're not going to want to use a `button`, just a normal `a` element. You can still change its default styles, but it will be much easier to use.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc i'm not very well with html, if i use a element, can i know if it's clicked or not ?

Comment: @Vahan I'm not sure what you mean by "can i know." How would you know? On the server? With JavaScript?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc On the server ?

Comment: @Vahan Are you trying to detect which link someone clicked? So that you know which column to sort by?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc i want to know is link clicked or not< every link has its unique name, so if i know how to check if it"s clicked, i will know which by its name

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can check this [JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/ryuhinata/y6eyc31w/) to see how it works. The suggested solution works wonder.

Html

```
<button class = "asText" id = "doSmth"> Hello World </button>
<div id="hiddenText">i'm well hidden</div>
```

CSS

```
.asText {
background:none;
border:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```